# emacs directory-local variable problem

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using a recent version of NTEmacs. 
I wrote a file named ".dir-locals.el" like following.

```
((nil . ((tab-width . 8)
        (fill-column . 70)))
 (c-mode . ((c-file-style . "GNU"))))
```

and I opened a c file in the subdirectory, I got an error message :

> Directory-local variables error:
>   (wrong-type-argument listp message)

I can't find out what's wrong with that code.

Answer (score 5):

The second part of the expression is a list of variables so you need more brackets

```
((nil . 
  ((tag-width . 8)
  (fill-column . 70)))
 (c-mode . 
 ((c-file-style . "GNU"))))
```

This worked for me. To get it working I added a quote at the beginning and evaluated the expression, then tracked it down from there.

Then removed the quote when it was working.

Comment: I tried with that exactly bracketed code, but it still says the same.

Comment: You may have missed my edit a few minutes ago, as the first try was mis-paste.

Comment: HaHa. Best thing to tell someone writing lisp: "...you need more brackets."

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue: emacs complaining with the same error on a .dir-locals.el file with similar content. In my case I've found the issue was in the invisible whitespace characters that were present in the file. (I've noticed Skype chat introduces weird space characters into text sometimes.) Once I've removed all extra whitespace, it worked.